# Multivariate Feature Selection

Tags: regression, feature-selection

I would like to perform a feature selection assuming I have a design matrix X (X_1, ..., X_84) and a multivariate target Y=[Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4]. So it's a multivariate multilinear regression. I ideally want to use Python RFE (Recursive Feature Elimination), LassoCV, and sm.OLS, except that Y must be a vector and not a matrix.

How could I deal with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to select two constants for RFE:

- 1. ***Regression method:***

---

```
* Which regression method will you use? 

  ***
  * Decision Tree Regressor?, Random Forest Regressor?, Linear Regressor? ...
    ***
```

- 2. ***Number of features:***

---

- How many features will you select for your problem? 1, 5?

  ---

  - Unfortunately, you have to set feature number as a constant.

For instance:

```py
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV

rfe = RFE(estimator=LassoCV(), n_features_to_select=5)
```

---

Possible Question: What should I do If I don't know how many features should I select?

---

Well, you can use [RFECV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html).

```py
rfe = RFECV(estimator=LassoCV())
```

Then you could continue with creating `Pipeline` and `fit` the model.

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

model = LassoCV()
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('s', rfe),('m', model)])
pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

Predict the next value:

```py
data = [[-7.05, 0.32, 0.94, ....]]
y_hat = pipeline.predict(data)
```

When you print the `y_hat`, you will get the next predicted value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but these function do not work with a multivariate target y...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, if possible could you show me an example sample of your data?